# Can't create views on tables generated through Azure Synapse Link Dataverse connector

Tags: powerapps, dataverse, azure-synapse-analytics

I'm trying to create a view in Synapse Analytics using a few tables that have been synced from a Power Apps solution using Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse. I get the error:

```
Operation CREATE/ALTER VIEW is not allowed for a replicated database.
```

The view is like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[HotelRooms]
AS
SELECT HotelName, RoomName
FROM dbo.Hotel
INNER JOIN dbo.Room
```

Is there any way to create views using tables synced from Dataverse? I was hoping there would be a solution that doesn't involve the extra step of an ADF pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to create a schema for views so that the replicated set and created views are separate.

You can do something similar to the below and you'll be able to see the view in Power BI for example.

From the database database or the Built-in allocated to the Synapse Workspace:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [BI] 
GO;

CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [BI].[SUM_TEST] 
AS
SELECT id,
    sum(hours) as sumhours
FROM [dataverse...].[dbo].[tablename]
group by id;

SELECT *
FROM [BI].[SUM_TEST];
```